# How to split multidimensional array into simple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've an **multidimensional array** like this which is list of choices made by the user. This is just an example of data retrieved from the user. The combination of sub arrays may vary as per user selection. 
Like 3 sub arrays having elements 3,5,2 respectively. And the arrays keys will also need to be from that ...

```
array(7) {
    ["resume_residence"]=>
    string(8) "Barbados"
    ["resume_language_fluently"]=>
    string(8) "Mandarin"
    ["resume_language_professional"]=>
    string(7) "Spanish"
    ["resume_language_basic"]=>
    string(8) "Mandarin"
    ["resume_overseas_experience"]=>
    string(2) "No"
    ["resume_degree"]=>     array(2) {
        [0]=>   string(2) "BA"
        [1]=>   string(3) "BFA"
    }
    ["resume_career_employment_status"]=>   array(2) {
        [0]=>   string(8) "Employed"
        [0]=>   string(10) "Unemployed"
    }
}
```

I want to **convert this array into multiple arrays** with each having single value key like

```
array(4){
    array(7) {
        ["resume_residence"]=>    string(8) "Barbados"
        ["resume_language_fluently"]=>    string(8) "Mandarin"
        ["resume_language_professional"]=>    string(7) "Spanish"
        ["resume_language_basic"]=>    string(8) "Mandarin"
        ["resume_overseas_experience"]=>    string(2) "No"
        ["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BA"
        ["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Employed"
    },
    array(7) {
        ["resume_residence"]=>    string(8) "Barbados"
        ["resume_language_fluently"]=>    string(8) "Mandarin"
        ["resume_language_professional"]=>    string(7) "Spanish"
        ["resume_language_basic"]=>    string(8) "Mandarin"
        ["resume_overseas_experience"]=>    string(2) "No"
        ["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BA"
        ["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Unemployed"
    },
    array(7) {
        ["resume_residence"]=>    string(8) "Barbados"
        ["resume_language_fluently"]=>    string(8) "Mandarin"
        ["resume_language_professional"]=>    string(7) "Spanish"
        ["resume_language_basic"]=>    string(8) "Mandarin"
        ["resume_overseas_experience"]=>    string(2) "No"
        ["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BFA"
        ["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Employed"
    },
    array(7) {
        ["resume_residence"]=>    string(8) "Barbados"
        ["resume_language_fluently"]=>    string(8) "Mandarin"
        ["resume_language_professional"]=>    string(7) "Spanish"
        ["resume_language_basic"]=>    string(8) "Mandarin"
        ["resume_overseas_experience"]=>    string(2) "No"
        ["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BFA"
        ["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Unemployed"
    }
}
```

Please help me how i can split the array into multiple arrays like the above one ..

Comment: So you always want to use the first value in `resume_degree` and `resume_career_employment_status`? Then just do `$array['resume_career_employment_status'] = $array['resume_career_employment_status'][0];` and the same for `resume_degree` and you're set.

Comment: No, I want to create multiple arrays with single value from each like in second array "resume_degree" should be "BFA".

Comment: does resume degree and resume career employment status match by count? do you want 0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2 matches?

Comment: No, Like for above array it should create 4 arrays with set of values like
----
["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BA"
["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Employed"
----
["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BFA"
["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Employed"
----
["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BA"
["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Unemployed"
----
["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BFA"
["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Unemployed"

Comment: You need to edit your question to explain and give proper examples of what the actual output should be. Looking at the comments, it's pretty unclear what you actually want. Please update the _question_ with clarifications. Don't post code in comment. since it's pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to generate all possible combinations of the array values assigned to the different keys in your input.

You can do this with recursion:

```
$array = [
    "resume_residence"=> "Barbados",
    "resume_language_fluently"=> "Mandarin",
    "resume_language_professional"=> "Spanish",
    "resume_language_basic"=> "Mandarin",
    "resume_overseas_experience"=> "No",
    "resume_degree"=> ["BA", "FBA"],
    "resume_career_employment_status"=> ["Employed", "Unemployed"]
];

function expandArrays(&$array) { // Argument by reference
    // Get current key and value based on the array pointer
    $key = key($array);
    $value = current($array);
    // Get results for any further key/values through recursion:
    $results = next($array) ? expandArrays($array) : [$array];
    // Nothing changes if the current value is not an array
    if (!is_array($value)) return $results;
    // It is an array, so produce all combinations of the partial results with each value
    foreach($value as $v) {
        foreach($results as $r) {
            $r[$key] = $v;
            $newResults[] = $r;
        }
    }
    // ... and return that as a result
    return $newResults;
}

$results = expandArrays($array);

print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [resume_residence] => Barbados
        [resume_language_fluently] => Mandarin
        [resume_language_professional] => Spanish
        [resume_language_basic] => Mandarin
        [resume_overseas_experience] => No
        [resume_degree] => BA
        [resume_career_employment_status] => Employed
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [resume_residence] => Barbados
        [resume_language_fluently] => Mandarin
        [resume_language_professional] => Spanish
        [resume_language_basic] => Mandarin
        [resume_overseas_experience] => No
        [resume_degree] => BA
        [resume_career_employment_status] => Unemployed
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [resume_residence] => Barbados
        [resume_language_fluently] => Mandarin
        [resume_language_professional] => Spanish
        [resume_language_basic] => Mandarin
        [resume_overseas_experience] => No
        [resume_degree] => FBA
        [resume_career_employment_status] => Employed
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [resume_residence] => Barbados
        [resume_language_fluently] => Mandarin
        [resume_language_professional] => Spanish
        [resume_language_basic] => Mandarin
        [resume_overseas_experience] => No
        [resume_degree] => FBA
        [resume_career_employment_status] => Unemployed
    )
)
```

Comment: Actually it should behave like the number of subsets created from main set. Like it should create 4 arrays with combination like below
----
["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BA"
["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Employed"
----
["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BFA"
["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Employed"
----
["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BA"
["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Unemployed"
----
["resume_degree"]=> string(2) "BFA"
["resume_career_employment_status"]=> string(2) "Unemployed"

Comment: I updated my answer after you gave these clarifications.

Comment: The number of sub arrays and their elements may vary. This is just an example of array having 2 sub arrays and 2 elements in each but it may vary like 3 sub arrays having 3,2 and 4 fields respectively.
The code you provide is using static key values while i want the code where it should take every key from array itself ...

Comment: It was not clear from your question that you might have other properties which also could have array values. You might want to update your question to clearly state this. I have updated my answer taking into account these requirements.

Comment: Thanks @trincot,  It works. I created the function myself but couldn't make it work as i didn't have idea where to use recursion ...